# ng-bind-html not working inside ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-bind-html

I am developing an angular app with angular 1.4 and ui.router 0.2.8. I am using ng-bind-html to print error messages while form validation.But it is not working.
In my controller

```
$scope.nameError = $sce.trustAsHtml("<p class='form-error'>Please enter your full name</p>");
```

In my html page ,inside

```
<span ng-bind-html="nameError"></span>
```

Showing no errors.How can I solve this issue and thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 'ngSanitize' set up in your application? Like:

```
   var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
    app.controller('myController', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.nameError = $sce.trustAsHtml("<p class='form-error'>
Please enter your full name</p>"); 
    });
```

You can try this reference:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers.@Und3rTow- Its working. But where is your answer to upvote

Answer (score 0):

either you can create a filter like @Und3rTow mentioned or you can create a function to convert it

```
$scope.trustFunc = function(nameError){
     return $sce.trustAsHtml("<p class='form-error'>Please enter your full name</p>");
}

<span ng-bind-html="trustFunc(nameError)"></span>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$sce){
  
$scope.trustFunc = function(nameError){
 return $sce.trustAsHtml("<p class='form-error'>Please enter your full name</p>");
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <span ng-bind-html="trustFunc(nameError)"></span>
</div>
```